# other alternative to the "Main Form" idea for structuring the application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, architecture

Most of questions I've read regarding winform applications have a form class as the main form that contains all application and call Application.Run with this main form

When the code in main form begins to growth, the form is divided into a no of user controls.

But here's what is annoying me. Forms and User Controls are supposed to be UI controls only, they shouldn't contain any logic for the program.

But still there's a wide use for the "main form" idea to handle the application's lifetime starting from the opening the application until the application close.

To avoid this, I have tried to provide the program logic in separate static "Manager" classes that manages separate parts of the program, and I manage them using the main form.

for example, I have the following "ThemesManager" Class

```
            public static class ThemesManager
            {
                public static void InstallTheme(string themefile) { }
                public static void ApplyTheme(Theme theme) { }
                public static void RemoveTheme(Theme theme) { }
                public static Theme[] GetThemes() { }
            }
```

and in the main form

```
            public class MainForm
            {
                void InstallTheme_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
                {
                // Call THeme.Install
                }

                void RemoveTheme_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
                {
                // Call THeme.Remove
                }
            }
```

now the application logic is somehow separated, but I think that I am destroying the application architecture with so many static classes as Many classes are depending on them. For example the user control that show the themes uses ThemesManager.GetThemes(). I feel that I am losing the basic concepts of OOP this way

so what other alternative do I have to separate logic from the UI, and not having a "Main Form" as the main component or controller of the application

Comment: First I would like to say that only `declarative style` can help you program with model and view separated, in `winforms` somehow you can't avoid partly mixed-up code between model and view. However there are some things in `winforms` which can help you separate the model and view as much as possible such as using `event`, `delegate`. In your case, you may want to define the class `ThemesManager` as `instance class`, initialize an instance of this class in your `MainForm` and use that instance in the whole program cycle.

Comment: Not sure about WinForms but in WPF have APP.XAML code behind.

Comment: @KingKing : yes we "avoid partly mixed-up code between model and view". but the problem is about making the view as the center part of the architecture. UI should be loosely coupled with other components to allow easy change of it, but this way I am treating as the main program

Comment: @Blam: I didn't understand your point. Can you please explain more?, Thanks.

Comment: There is a design pattern named `MVP` usually used for winform. On the other hand, I don't recommend static `ThemesManager` class. Instead, make it as an instance at the main form. The reason is to ensure concurrency safety and prefent race conditions.

Comment: @Fendy: I have read some tutorials for MVP pattern but It wasn't what I am looing for, but after quite searching I think "Passive View" which is a variation of the MVP and MVC might be useful for my case. I am still working to see if I can accomplish the separation UI with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use design patterns such as:

- Model–view–presenter (MVP);
- Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM);
- Model–view–controller (MVC).

They are great for separating the logic layer from the user interface layer.
You can see some examples [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained). This one is for Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) and works for me.

The good thing about design patterns is that they make your code testable.